# python : Esperar evento no teclado, com script minimizado?

Tags: python, windows

Gostaria de saber se existe uma forma de detectar eventos no teclado com meu script minimizado.

Já tentei varios metodos como `msvcrt.getch()`, `input("")` e outros mas eles só funcionam com o foco na janela do script.

O fluxo do programa é o seguinte:

Função Main

```
 1 - Espera um evento(qualquer) no teclado
 2 - Se houver um evento
        Funçãoqualquer()
 3 - Se não
        retorna para a função Main
```

Comment: Você pode usar o pyhook para hookar o evento do teclado http://pyhook.sourceforge.net/doc_1.5.0/

Answer (score 0):

Como dito anteriormente, pode-se usar a biblioteca [PyHook](https://pypi.org/project/pyHook/) que monitora a atividade do usuário através de suas entradas do teclado ou mouse.
Esbarrei em um [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8BiOPBsXh0g) que mostra um exemplo eficaz de salvar os inputs do teclado de maneira 'silenciosa' usando o PyHook:

> ```
> import pyHook, pythomcom, sys, logging
> ```

```
file_log='C:\\important\\log.txt' #Define onde as entradas serão salvas

def OnKeyboardEvent(event): #Configurações do log 
    logging.basicConfig(filename=file_log, level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(message)s')
    chr(event.Ascii)
    logging.log(10,chr(event.Ascii))
    return True

hooks_manager = pyHook.HookManager() 
hooks_manager.KeyDown = OnKeyboardEvent 
hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()
pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

O código pode ser um pouco 'antigo' mas é um exemplo claro de como seria tal funcionalidade.
Para que o script funcione de forma silenciosa **de fato** é preciso ser salvo no formato **[pyw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34739315/pyw-files-in-python-program)** que faz com que o mesmo execute sem abrir uma tela de execução.

OBS: No vídeo citado é dito que tal técnica pode ser usada de maneira maliciosa então use-a de forma consciente.